# Retrieve Data from stored procedure in SQL into asp.net without Postback

Tags: javascript, sql, asp.net, ajax, stored-procedures

I'm new to Asp.net and web development, I have an application that makes some calculation based on the selected dates on the form and gets some data from sql db, every time the user change the date the from should be updated with the latest calculations, means a post back, which a bit annoying, what I want is what is the best way / method / language to retrieve the data into my from without post back the form?, is it possible with JavaScript?, I tried the update panel, but still annoying and slow with big calculations, could you please give me an example to start with as I have the below stored procedure on my database, and let's say that I have a TextBox will get the returned Value of @category:

```
 alter PROCEDURE Test2sp 
    
 @id_ref  nvarchar(50),
 @category  nvarchar(50) output
 as
BEGIN
    
    select @category= category from employees where id_ref=@id_ref
    
END
GO
```

Comment: You seem to know about AJAX - as you tagged your question with it. What's stopping you from using it? Or HTTP Fetch? Or web sockets?

Answer (score 0):

Well, software is part science, but part art so to speak.

So, in software, RARE that "one solution" is the best.

So, in your question the goal is to avoid a post-back.

But, you should supply more information as to why that post-back is to be avoided.

> > means a post back, which a bit annoying,

Hum, ok, not really a solid narrative here.

The issue is we have quite a few choices. And thus which road and choice will depend.

For example, OFTEN we can as a quick and easy soluion?

We can introduce what is called a update-panel.

They are easy to setup, and they reduce efforts (developer cost's) on your part.

However, if you abuse use of up-date panels, then you wind up not saving performance, but might save developer cost and time!!

We all don't have un-limited time or unlimited government budgets for our software choices.

So, update panels are OFTEN lamented by many in asp.net land, but I happen to be a great fan of them. In fact, I find them downright amazing!!!

The reason for using a update panel (UP in this disscuion) are you eliminate the need to write client side browser code, get to use nice code behind, and in MOST cases are a viable choice and soluion.

So, what a UP does is allow you to update only parts of the browser (just in case everyone is wondering - razor pages attempt the same goal, but do this in a different way).

You don't mention/note when you want this calualation to occur. For example, are you wanting to use the control/text changed event?

Or, does user change the value, and have to hit some button?

Anway, we assume now that you have the code behind that calls and gets the information you want working.

Since you spent that time and money and effort to build that code?

Then give a UP a try!!

Just enclose that date and button inside of a UP, and you get what is called a "partial page" post back. That means that ONLY that part of the page will be sent to the server. And this means no flicker on the page, no scroling postion changes. In fact, quite much NEAR ALL of what you acheive with a ajax call will be the result.

But, keep in mind that while this looks and talks and quacks like a ajax call?

The page life cycle DOES run. That certanly means that page load will run. But, if the page been designed that you have the

```
 if (!IsPostBack) 
 {
      // the REAL first page load code goes here
      // code to load drop downs, combo's, pick lists etc.
      // code to load data and grids etc.
 }
```

So, we design all pages with above in mind, since no need to re-load data on each post-back and round trip, right????

So, using a UP

Drag in  a script manager (put it right below the page form tag.

Then take your date field/control (whatever) and the button you NOW have to run code behind to get that data.

The controls you need to operate on (update) need to be included inside of this update panel. (don't put more of the page into the UP then you need).

the pattern lookes like this:

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            
            // put markup of button and controls here

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

So, in above, put your button + date control in above. Try running it.

You not see a page post back, you are free to use code behind. And you not see any page flicker. it really is like magic.

Behind the scenes, you get a ajax setup, but without all the hassle.

Do give the above a try - you find the results amazing and beautifal - and effort less, since you get to use + write 100% server side code.

The next choice?

Create a static method in the current web page, and then use a ajax call.

This approach is about the best choice, but it more efforts, and you don't in code behind have any use of controls in the current web page (so the ajax post call has to pass any values required from the web page. and on return of that ajax call, then the client side js code has to update the controls on the page.

So best choice? Well, a ajax call in "somewhat" better, but then again, it reuqires far more efforts (and thus more cost).

Try the update panel. You be rather amazed, since it oh so easy to remove a post-back on given webform pages.

However, do keep in mind, that a page life cycle STILL occurs, but it only now the part you placed in that UP.